# JOIN Tables based on Service Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, left-join

I have 2 Tables (**History** and **Responsible**). They need to be JOINED based on Service Date.

History Table:

| Id | ServiceDate | Hours | ClientId | ClientName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-15 | 3 | 123 | Tom Holland |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 | 5 | 123 | Tom Holland |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 2 | 123 | Tom Holland |

Responsible Table:

*2999-12-31 means Responsible has no end date (current)*

| ClientId | ClientName | ResponsibleId | ResponsibleName | ResponsibleStartDate | ResponsibleEndtDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Tom Holland | 77 | Thomas Anderson | 2020-09-17 | 2021-10-17 |
| 123 | Tom Holland | 88 | Tom Cruise | 2021-10-18 | 2999-12-31 |
| 123 | Tom Holland | 99 | Sten Lee | 2022-01-07 | 2999-12-31 |

My code produces multiple rows, because 2022-01-14 Service date falls under multiple date ranges from Responsible Table:

```
SELECT h.Id, 
       h.ServiceDate, 
       h.Hours, 
       h.ClientId, 
       h.ClientName, 
       r.ResponsibleName
FROM History AS h
LEFT JOIN Responsible AS r
   ON (h.ClientId = r.ClientId AND h.ServiceDate BETWEEN r.ResponsibleStartDate AND r.ResponsibleEndtDate)
```

The output of the query above is:

| Id | ServiceDate | Hours | ClientId | ClientName | ResponsibleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-15 | 3 | 123 | Tom Holland | Thomas Anderson |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 | 5 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 2 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 2 | 123 | Tom Holland | Sten Lee |

Technically, output is correct (because 2022-01-14 is between 2021-10-18 - 2999-12-31 as well between 2022-01-07 - 2999-12-31), but not what I need.

I would like to know if possible to achieve 2 outputs:

**1) If Service Date falls in multiple date ranges from Responsible Table, Responsible Should be the person who's ResponsibleStartDate is closer to the ServiceDate:**

| Id | ServiceDate | Hours | ClientId | ClientName | ResponsibleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-15 | 3 | 123 | Tom Holland | Thomas Anderson |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 | 5 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 2 | 123 | Tom Holland | Sten Lee |

**2) Keep all rows, if Service Date falls in multiple date ranges from Responsible Table, but split Hours evenly between Responsible:**

| Id | ServiceDate | Hours | ClientId | ClientName | ResponsibleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-15 | 3 | 123 | Tom Holland | Thomas Anderson |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 | 5 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 1 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 1 | 123 | Tom Holland | Sten Lee |

Comment: And if hours are odd (say, 1 and 4)? Do you want 2.5 or one becomes 3 and the other is 2?

Comment: If there are 3 Responsible for date range and 10 hours, then each will have 3.33 hours (10 hours/3 responsible)

Comment: Ok, wasn't clear from sample data if you wanted true average or wanted to stay in int. Might be useful to include such a case.

Comment: Also, why do you store `ClientName` in both places (or either place, really, this is data that should only be in the `Clients` table)? If a client changes their name do you change it everywhere or only in _future_ rows in history / responsible?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, this is the fake data I created from scratch as an example. You are absolutely correct, ClientName should be stored only in the Client Table. Pretend it was already joined. I will edit the post to fix it.

Comment: It's not going to change solutions, I don't think you need to change the post, I was merely hoping the tables weren't actually designed this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one, we can use a window function to apply a row number, based on how close to `ServiceDate` the `ResponsibleStartDate` is, then we can just pick the first row per `h.Id`. If there is a tie we can break it by picking something that will give us deterministic order, e.g. `ORDER BY {DATEDIFF expression}, ResponsibleName`.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT h.Id, 
       h.ServiceDate, 
       h.Hours, 
       h.ClientId, 
       h.ClientName, 
       r.ResponsibleName, 
       RankOrderedByProximityToServiceDate = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY h.Id 
          ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, ResponsibleStartDate, ServiceDate)))
  FROM dbo.History AS h
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Responsible AS r
     ON (h.ClientId = r.ClientId 
     AND h.ServiceDate BETWEEN r.ResponsibleStartDate AND r.ResponsibleEndtDate)
)
SELECT Id, ServiceDate, Hours, ClientId, ClientName, ResponsibleName
FROM cte WHERE RankOrderedByProximityToServiceDate = 1;
```

Output:

| Id | ServiceDate | Hours | ClientId | ClientName | ResponsibleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-15 | 3 | 123 | Tom Holland | Thomas Anderson |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 | 5 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 2 | 123 | Tom Holland | Sten Lee |

Second one doesn't require a CTE, we can simply divide the `Hours` in `h` by the number of rows that exist for that `h.Id`, then limit it to 2 decimal places:

```
SELECT h.Id, 
       h.ServiceDate,
       Hours = CONVERT(decimal(11,2), 
         h.Hours * 1.0
         / COUNT(h.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY h.Id)),
       h.ClientId, 
       h.ClientName, 
       r.ResponsibleName
FROM dbo.History AS h
LEFT JOIN dbo.Responsible AS r
   ON (h.ClientId = r.ClientId 
   AND h.ServiceDate BETWEEN r.ResponsibleStartDate AND r.ResponsibleEndtDate);
```

Output:

| Id | ServiceDate | Hours | ClientId | ClientName | ResponsibleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-15 | 3.00 | 123 | Tom Holland | Thomas Anderson |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 | 5.00 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 1.00 | 123 | Tom Holland | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 1.00 | 123 | Tom Holland | Sten Lee |

Both demonstrated in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c3d93029b5cbe2392f9c841410eb973).

Comment: Surely "ResponsibleStartDate closest to ServiceDate" is simply "most recent ResponsibleStartDate for this client and ServiceDate" given ServiceDate is on or after ResponsibleStartDate?

Comment: @Jack I use a row number because it's easier to break a tie (the problem in your solution with joining on a max), and yes that should always be ServiceDate before but ABS() for "closest date" is a hard habit to break.

Comment: Thank You, Aaron, really appreciated the help. One more question. If there are 2 Responsible persons with same ResponsibleStartDate and ResponsibleEndDate (let's say 2021-01-20 - current). And service date is 2021-01-25, for example. Will your code work in that case for the 1st question? In that case any of them can be Responsible.

Comment: Yes if there is a tie, it will pick one arbitrarily. You can add additional tie-breakers to the `ORDER BY`, e.g. `, ResponsibleName` to order alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at part 1 - it doesn't work if there's more than one Responsible as of the same start date.

```
WITH
"all_services" AS (
    SELECT
        h.Id, 
        h.ServiceDate, 
        h.Hours, 
        h.ClientId, 
        h.ClientName, 
        r.ResponsibleName,
        r.ResponsibleStartDate
    FROM History AS h
    LEFT JOIN Responsible AS r
           ON h.ClientId = r.ClientId
          AND h.ServiceDate BETWEEN r.ResponsibleStartDate AND r.ResponsibleEndtDate
),
"most_recent_key" AS (
    SELECT
        ServiceDate,
        ClientId,
        MAX(ResponsibleStartDate) AS "ResponsibleStartDate"
    FROM all_services
    GROUP BY ServiceDate, ClientId
)
SELECT Id, ServiceDate, Hours, ClientId, ClientName, ResponsibleName
FROM all_services
INNER JOIN most_recent_key
     USING (ServiceDate, ClientId, ResponsibleStartDate)
```

Posting it anyway as a contrast to Aaron's better solution as a learning point for myself.

Comment: `GROUP BY 1, 2` and `USING` are not [tag:sql-server] syntax.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I'd missed that tag. My own experience is all in PostgreSQL and occasionally Oracle...